# Mark a branch as master or integration

Tags: git

Is there some way to mark / demarcate a Git branch as the master branch or integration branch using Git itself?

Naming conventions are nice, but I am looking for another way.

Comment: i dont think git by itself has that concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than simply using a named branch such as `rel-1.0`, you can use Git's [tagging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) feature:

> Like most VCSs, Git has the ability to tag specific points in history
>   as being important. Typically people use this functionality to mark
>   release points (v1.0, and so on).